# Android send interface through Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an activity (ActivityA) that implements an interface (InterfaceA).
When I want to display an other activity I use this code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
// intent.putExtra("interface", this);
startActivity(intent);
```

And ActivityA

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity implements InterfaceA, Serializable
```

And then in ActivityB

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Serializable s = intent.getExtras().getSerializable("interface");
if(s != null && s instanceof InterfaceA)
   iInterface = (InterfaceA)s;
```

But I get an error during

```
android java.io.NotSerializableException
```

Is it possible to send an Activity through an Intent (like delegate in Objective-C ?

Thanks

Comment: it is not a delegate. getSerializable expects a Serializable object. `Activity` is not implementing Serializable

Comment: So, how can I do to perform an action on the previous activity ?

Comment: Why do you want transport interface? What kind of code do you want?

Comment: In ActivityB, I'm creating a new local object I want to display in ActivityA without having to refresh the listView in ActivityA. So I would like to have send an interface to AcitivtyB (Implementation is in AcitivtyA) Is it possible ? I do such similar things using delegate in ObjectiveC between UIViewController ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In ActivityB, I'm creating a new local object I want to display in
>   ActivityA without having to refresh the listView in ActivityA.

You can start `ActivityB` for result in `ActivityA` as this will not recreate the `ActivityA`. And when you receive the result from `ActivityB`, add new object in list and call adapter's `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

**In ActivityA**,

```
public static final int REQ_CODE = 1;

// Starting an activity
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE );
```

And override this method to get the result

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == REQ_CODE)
        {
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            {
                // Add the object in list and call adapter's notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }
    }
```

In **ActivityB**,

```
Intent data = new Intent();
// Put the new object as Serializable in Intent
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
// And finally, close the activity
finish();
```

Comment: John smith   If this is the Answer then change Title of your question pls.. because this answer is alternative aproach to solve your problem. Thanks.